# Is there a way to call externals from an xsl stylesheet?

Tags: xslt, libxslt

I very often use the document() xslt function to access an external XML file and use that in the transformation. If I provide a URL within the function I can also access RESTfull web service from the xslt and use the XML this service returns in my xslt. But now i have a local program that returns XML and I would like to address it the same way. I could turn it into a service and access it that way, but it would be nice if I could make the XSLT processor (libxslt) to start the program and return the output. Th EXSLT site does not seem to refer to that kind of functions. Somebody out there who has solved this problem ?

Comment: Wild. Are you saying that you apply xslt-1 to an xml file, and then xslt-1 downloads xslt-2 to do the true transformation to the original xml file?

Comment: So you want your XSLT to get XML from a generator program through a function call? Maybe what you really want is a scripting language like ANT, Python, or even regular old shell scripting to tie your pieces together.

Comment: Someone with the necessary rights might want to correct the spelling in the question title so that it shows up in searches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`URIResolver`](http://today.java.net/download/jdk6/doc/api/javax/xml/transform/URIResolver.html) and a custom URI scheme. You that can then redirect certain URI references to read from any source.

Comment: Well, not really. I am not using Java. I use the libxslt library. I can ofcourse write an extension and use it, like you could by writing a URIResolver in you java example. i just wanted to know if anybody has done this using libxslt.